# How to get dynamically inserted component's reference in Angular with ContentChild?

Tags: angular

I have a mat-tab in my component (DetailsComponent), and each tab hosts its own component, but they are inserted dynamically at runtime, meaning that they are not in the Details component's template.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
    // Dynamically inserted tab components
    <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

When my Details page loads, it'll default to the first tab, which is not the one I need, the one I'm looking for (TargetsComponent) is not yet in the DOM.

I have the following code to retrieve the TargetsComponent:

```
@ContentChild(TargetsComponent) private targets!: TargetsComponent;

public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
  console.log(this.targets);
}
```

Understandably, this is undefined when the page loads, however, my problem is, that the variable is not being reassigned when the DOM changes (I go to the Targets tab), as opposed to the documentation:

> You can use ContentChild to get the first element or the directive
>   matching the selector from the content DOM.  **If the content DOM
>   changes, and a new child matches the selector, the property will be
>   updated.**

I've tried manual change detection `this.changeDetector.detectChanges();` when the tab is changed to no avail. Is there anyway to force Angular to recheck ContentChildren? Or is there a better way to get the reference of this dynamically inserted component?

Comment: It'd also work if I could make each tab to load its content to the DOM eagerly.